# Problems setting up Ubuntu Machine as a router

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, dhcp

I have been at this for over 24 hours, here is what I have so far.

- I have an Ubuntu Server running version 14.04.2.amd64, called **SV-01**
- **SV-01** has two NICs. **ETH1** is for the external network (goes to a router, then the internet). **ETH0** is for the internal network (goes to a  switch, then my computers/devices)
- I have, currently, one single ubuntu workstation, running 14.04.2 LTS (64 bit if I am not mistaken), called **WS-01**
- I have, currently, one Windows 7 64 bit workstation, called **WS-02**
- I want **WS-01** and **WS-02** to get their IPs dynamically from **SV-01** acting as a DHCP server
- Using [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router), I set up `SV-01:/etc/network/interfaces` like so

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  #Internet NIC
  auto eth1
          iface eth1 inet static
          address 192.168.0.19
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          broadcast 192.168.0.255
          network 192.168.0.0
          gateway 192.168.0.1

  #Internal NIC
  auto eth0
          iface eth0 inet static
          address 192.168.66.254
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          broadcast 192.168.66.255
          network 192.168.0.0
  ```
- using [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router), I enabled IP forwarding and msqaurading

  ```
  #Script for setting up machine as a router
  #Downloaded from
  #https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

  echo -e "\n\nLoading simple rc.firewall-iptables version $FWVER..\n"
  DEPMOD=/sbin/depmod
  MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe

  EXTIF="eth1"
  INTIF="eth0"
  #INTIF2="eth0"
  echo "   External Interface:  $EXTIF"
  echo "   Internal Interface:  $INTIF"

  #======================================================================
  #== No editing beyond this line is required for initial MASQ testing ==
  echo -en "   loading modules: "
  echo "  - Verifying that all kernel modules are ok"
  $DEPMOD -a
  echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
  echo -en "ip_tables, "
  $MODPROBE ip_tables
  echo -en "nf_conntrack, "
  $MODPROBE nf_conntrack
  echo -en "nf_conntrack_ftp, "
  $MODPROBE nf_conntrack_ftp
  echo -en "nf_conntrack_irc, "
  $MODPROBE nf_conntrack_irc
  echo -en "iptable_nat, "
  $MODPROBE iptable_nat
  echo -en "nf_nat_ftp, "
  $MODPROBE nf_nat_ftp
  echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
  echo -e "   Done loading modules.\n"
  echo "   Enabling forwarding.."
  echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  echo "   Enabling DynamicAddr.."
  echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr
  echo "   Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy.."

  iptables-restore <<-EOF
  *nat
  -A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
  COMMIT
  *filter
  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  -A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD -j LOG
  COMMIT
  EOF

  echo -e "\nrc.firewall-iptables v$FWVER done.\n"
  ```
- Using [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server), I set up `SV-01:/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server/default` to `INTERFACES="eth0"`
- Using [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server), I set up `SV-01:/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to

  ```
  ddns-update-style none;

  option domain-name "example.org";
  option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;

  log-facility local7;

  host ws-01 {
          hardware ethernet a0:d3:c1:1f:6f:1e;
          fixed-address 192.168.66.1;
  ```
- Finally, I have the following for `WS-01:/etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback
  auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet dhcp
  ```

The problem is if I issue the command `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` on **WS-01**, the dhcp server is never found. `sudo dhclient` returns blank. `cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases` shows the ISP router IP of `192.168.0.1`.

Someone please help me out as I have hit a brick wall.

**EDIT**

Output of SV-01: `route -n`:

```
Destination   Gateway      Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
0.0.0.0       192.168.0.1  0.0.0.0        UG     0       0    0    eth1
192.168.0.0   0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    eth1
192.168.66.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    eth0
```

Output of WS-01: `route -n`:

```
Destination   Gateway      Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
192.168.66.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    eth0
```

Is it significant that there is no `UG` in **WS-01**?

Comment: First: did you check if the DHCP server is actually running? Also, you may need a `subnet` statement for `192.158.66.0/24` in the DHCP config or else it may not listen and serve on that subnet. Finally, you should be aware that you are creating a double NAT situation here. You should preferably get rid of one of the two redundant routers.

Comment: @Celada How do I check if dhcp server is running? Can you be more specific as to where I add this `subnet` statment? I will look into disabling the other router.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is to enhance your knowledge on routing on Linux, but if it is not, I'd like to suggest using OpenWrt for this job.

OpenWrt already has interface management, DHCP server, firewall, port forward, IPv6 support and other services all available from either the CLI or a web interface.

OpenWrt can be installed either on a cheap machine, many routers (maybe yours!), and virtual machine.  Using a virtual machine as a router appliance is also a great way to isolate your host, which may be running multiple services, from the Internet.

You can use libvirt to virtualize an OpenWrt router, map the WAN network card directly inside the VM and bridge the LAN card as another card in the VM.

Download for OpenWrt are available at https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/x86/kvm_guest/ this version is to boot from libvirt.

Beyond that, if your DHCP server isn't starting like Celada said in the comments, you should try starting DHCP in the foreground using "dhcpd -d -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf" to see any error in the output.

Using "tail -f /var/log/syslog" in another terminal can also give you a hand.